# how to solve session swaping or session expire issue in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am facing session **swapping or session expire** issue in Oracle APEX. Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As of session timeout:

- connect as ADMIN to your Apex
- Manage Instance
- Security
- Session Timeout - set those numbers to *larger* values than they currently are

Alternatively, there's the same option in your own application - it can be found within Shared Components. If it is not set, it'll take values set for the instance (or the workspace).

I don't know what *session swapping* is.

Answer (score 0):

Help us help you. Always include the version number of the software you are asking about and what steps you have tried and what the outcome was.

You can control session timeout at the individual Application Level. Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/htmdb/managing-application-attributes.html#GUID-33A67D5E-1128-4D23-9C5C-15FC9BE1B783) : Session Management

Use Session Management attributes to reduce exposure by application to abandoned computers with an open web browser.
No idea what session swappin gis.